# Eclipse Indexer with IAR plugin

Tags: c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt, iar, indexer

I'm using IAR plugin to develop code for uC RL78.

I have the following sample code :

```
/* Include the processor-specific SFR file where "DEVICE"
   corresponds to your selected device or device family. */
#include "ior5f10pmh.h"
#include "ior5f10pmh_ext.h"
int main() {
PM6_bit.no1 = 0;
return 0;
}
```

The problem is that the indexer detects an error as specified in the image below

[image: Indexer Image]

The indexer detect this error because it is not able to resolve correctly the two #includes because in the two header files it checks on the predefined preprocessor symbols "__CORE__" which is specified in the compilation options.

Is there any workaround to let the indexer index correctly the two header files ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the iar plugin but the normal way is to enable "Use active build configuration" under Preferences -> C/C++ -> Indexer.

With this configuration the indexer detects the compilation options.